# New navigation causes body to overflow the window

Tags: bug, navigation, new-nav

Great job guys!

Unfortunately the new navigation causes the site to overflow the window slightly, allowing me to scroll right. This only happens when using the favorite tags filter, because the feeds link at the bottom of the page doesn't wrap to a new line.

Using Chrome 43.0.2357.125 on Linux.

<sub>[I've come up with a fix if you're interested](https://gist.github.com/humbleRumble/6b3922e3ea5bf900f41d)</sub>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good catch and thanks for the fix.